# Need help parsing wikipedia json api in SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, api, uiimageview, wikipedia-api

Below is the json for a WIKI page. (the format is probably way off, so here's a link where it nicer to see: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&titles=John_F._Kennedy&pithumbsize=500)

> {
>       "batchcomplete": "",
>       "query": {
>           "normalized": [
>               {
>                   "from": "John_F._Kennedy",
>                   "to": "John F. Kennedy"
>               }
>           ],
>           "pages": {
>               "5119376": {
>                   "pageid": 5119376,
>                   "ns": 0,
>                   "title": "John F. Kennedy",
>                   "thumbnail": {
>                       "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/John_F._Kennedy%2C_White_House_photo_portrait%2C_looking_up.jpg/385px-John_F._Kennedy%2C_White_House_photo_portrait%2C_looking_up.jpg",
>                       "width": 385,
>                       "height": 500
>                   },
>                   "pageimage": "John_F._Kennedy,_White_House_photo_portrait,_looking_up.jpg"
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }

I made my structs to represent the json keys, but I can't figure out what struct or var I can write to represent the number 5119376, which apparently is an object. all the other key values are strings and do not change. But this key is strange because it is an integer AND it changes from wiki page to wiki page. So I don't know what to name that key because it's supposedly a number AND it changes with every page.

I tried printing out the whole object to see how it looks in the console:

> {
>   WikiStruct(query: quote_project.QueryStruct(pages: Optional(quote_project.PageStruct(pageid: nil, ns: nil, title: nil, thumbnail: nil, pageimage: nil))), batchcomplete: Optional(""))
>   }

So the computer got that "batchcomplete is an empty string "", and it also picks up the normalized stuff. But it says that everything inside the weird 5119376 object is nil. My ultimate goal, by the way, is to access the url that gives the main jpg image of the wiki page

The error I get is then this:

```
 Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

My structs are below. I've tried both ignoring the 5119376 object and attempting to create some sort of struct for it, but to no avail

```
struct WikiStruct: Decodable {

var query: QueryStruct
var batchcomplete: String?

}

struct QueryStruct: Decodable {

var normalized: [NormalizedStruct]?
var pages: PageStruct?

}

struct NormalizedStruct: Decodable{

var from: String?
var to: String?
}

struct PageStruct: Decodable{

var pageid: Int?
var ns: Int?
var title: String?
var thumbnail: ThumbStruct?
var pageimage: String?

}

struct ThumbStruct: Decodable{

var source: String?//this is what I want
var width: Int?
var height: Int?

}
```

Comment: I've never used SWIFT but had similar problems in python as you need the pageid to be able to transfer json to a dataframe. Is there any way you can access the pageid and use that to create a struct? Or rename it in the json?

Answer (score 2):

Had this exact same issue today. Managed to solve it. Basically the data nested under pages is a keyed object, with the key being 5119376. To parse this just change the pages variable in QueryStruct to a dictionary. Like this:

```
struct QueryStruct: Decodable {

var normalized: [NormalizedStruct]?
var pages: [String:PageStruct]?

}
```

After this I'm able to parse the object successfully. Print of the WikiStruct Object:

`WikiStruct(query: QueryStruct(normalized: [NormalizedStruct(from: "John_F._Kennedy", to: "John F. Kennedy")], pages: ["5119376": PageStruct(pageid: 5119376, ns: 0, title: "John F. Kennedy", thumbnail: ThumbStruct(source: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/John_F._Kennedy%2C_White_House_color_photo_portrait.jpg/385px-John_F._Kennedy%2C_White_House_color_photo_portrait.jpg", width: 385, height: 500), pageimage: "John_F._Kennedy,_White_House_color_photo_portrait.jpg")]), batchcomplete: "")`