# Parse Wiki Nearby

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, and trying to figure out how to parse the JSON returned by Wiki Nearby. With the help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqo844saoC4 here's where I am right now:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gscoord=37.7891838%7C-122.4033522&gsradius=10000&gslimit=2&format=json"
        getData(from: url)
        
        
    }
    
    private func getData(from url: String) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }

            
            var result: Response?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            }
            catch {
                print("failed to convert \(error.localizedDescription) ")
            }
            
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            
            print(type(of: json.query.geosearch))
            print(json.query.geosearch.self)
            
            
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
}



struct Response: Codable {
    let batchcomplete: String
    let query: Query
}

struct Query: Codable {
    let geosearch: [Geosearch]?
}

struct Geosearch: Codable {
    
    let pageid: Int?
    let title: String?
}
```

Following [Need help parsing wikipedia json api in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415777/need-help-parsing-wikipedia-json-api-in-swift) I believe that geosearch is a dictionary. The code runs, but how do I retrieve the title or pageid from geosearch (print(json.query.geosearch.title) gives an error)?

Sorry - probably something really basic... any pointers would be appreciated.

Philipp

Comment: For anyone having similar questions, this video is excellent: https://youtu.be/_TrPJQWD8qs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code. It uses a completion closure to "wait" until the results are fetched before
returning them. Since `geosearch` is an array you need to loop through it. Note, the json response is parsed without errors. Works for me.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gscoord=37.7891838%7C-122.4033522&gsradius=10000&gslimit=2&format=json"
        
        getData(from: url) { response in
            if let result = response,
               let geosearch = result.query.geosearch {
                print("-----> result: \(result) \n")
                for geo in geosearch {
                    print("geo.title: \(geo.title)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
   func getData(from url: String, completion: @escaping(Response?) -> ()) {
    if let theURL = URL(string: url) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: theURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                completion(result)
            } catch {
                print("failed to convert \(error) ")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the item of array to get the pageid or title like:

```
print(json.query.geosearch?[0].title ?? "")
```

Since the json returns an array

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "geosearch": [
      {
        "pageid": 18618509,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Wikimedia Foundation",
        "lat": 37.78916666666667,
        "lon": -122.40333333333334,
        "dist": 2.5,
        "primary": ""
      },
      {
        "pageid": 42936625,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Foxcroft Building",
        "lat": 37.78916666666667,
        "lon": -122.40333333333334,
        "dist": 2.5,
        "primary": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(json.query.geosearch.self) //This will store the repsone in the let geosearch: [Geosearch]?


//You can check the individual result for the 1st and 2nd object 
print(json.query.geosearch[0].pageid)//18618509
print(json.query.geosearch[0].title) //"Wikimedia Foundation"

print(json.query.geosearch[1].pageid)//42936625
print(json.query.geosearch[1].title) //"Foxcroft Building"
```